# Can a continuous function on [0,1] be constructed which is differentiable exactly at two points in [0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis

We see that we can find a function nowhere differentiable or finitely not differentiable.
But I want to understand, can a continuous function on $[0,1]$ be constructed which is differentiable exactly at two points in $[0,1]$?
How can I construct such a function which is finitely differentiable?

Comment: Just multiply the Weierstrass function by a function that tends to zero quickly enough at exactly two points, say $x^2(x-1)^2$ and use that Weierstrass' is Holder.

Comment: @Pp..: That works but there is no need to square, or to use Holder.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a function that is continuous everywhere and differentiable nowhere, call it $g$.

Take $2$ points, $a$ and $b$.  Then $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)g(x)$ is continuous everywhere, differentiable only at $a$ and $b$.

---

You can use continuity of $g$ and the definition of the derivative to verify very quickly that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $b$.   To see that $f$ is differentiable nowhere else, you could note that if $f$ were differentiable at $c\not\in \{a,b\}$, then so would be $g(x) =\dfrac{f(x)}{(x-a)(x-b)}$ by the quotient rule.

Comment: how can a function be continuous everywhere and differentiable nowhere? Does such a function exist?

Comment: @Jason: The [most famous example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) was brought to us by Weierstrass, but there are many others.  They seem rare from ordinary experience in calculus, and yet in some sense, differentiability is such a strong condition that it is the rare special case (in some precise senses like [Baire category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem)).